# Rate of increase of area using length of side

Tags: derivatives

The length of the side of a square is increasing at a rate of 4cm/s. Find the rate of increase of the area when the length of the side is 5cm.

I know I have to use the formula for area to find the rate of increase of the area, but i'm not sure how to put that into a formula and find the increase of area when given the side.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: let $f(t)$ be the side, then find $\big(f^2(t)\big)'$ when $f(t)=5\,$.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the square, in terms of its side length, is $A(s) = s^2$. The rate of change of the area, with respect to the side length, is $\frac{dA}{ds} = 2s$.

The rate of change of the side length, with respect to time, is a constant $\frac{ds}{dt} = 4 \mbox{ cm/s}$.

The rate of change of the area, with respect to time, is $\frac{dA}{dt}$. Given $\frac{dA}{ds}$ and $\frac{ds}{dt}$, what can you do to find $\frac{dA}{dt}$?